# UVProject why no detail in the cusp surface image?

Tags: image, project

I have UVProject working... projecting an image on a flat surface extruded from a cube. But when I repeat this on the cusp surface (see image) it becomes a diffuse color ie no detail of the image. I imagine this is because of the extreme complexity of the cusp surface, is there some way the cusp surface can be treated to accept an image, and eventually a movie clip?

[image: cusp surface and flat object projection]

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Denis, can you show us your settings, (Material and Modifier).. or perhaps, more simply, share your file, following the instructions  on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I checked your file. The cusp surface don't even has a UVMap. What did you mean on UV projecting?

Comment: So how would I reproduce on the cusp surface what is working on the flat plate ie projection of an image or video?